# complex calculation process between rows one of them may be null

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have one complex calculation process on the row
i want to do multiplication of two fields (val1) if my condition equal to true then
do another multiplication of another two fields (val 2) 
Then I calculate the percentage of total values ((val1 + val2) * 10%) / 100
the problem is the any condotion maybe equal to false then the result equal to null
this is my code

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      r.paymentDate as "Payment Date" ,
      r.recivedID as "Recived ID" ,
      f.farmerName as "Farmer Name" ,   
      ra.tips as "percentage ",     


          ( ( (SELECT SUM(od.price * od.kilo) FROM orderDetailsTBL od WHERE od.recivedID = r. recivedID AND r.status = @STATUS AND od.calcType = 'k') +
            (SELECT SUM(od.quant * od.price) FROM orderDetailsTBL od WHERE od.recivedID = r. recivedID AND r.status = @STATUS AND od.calcType = 'n')  ) * ra.tips) / 100
                 as [amount]
FROM recivedTBL r
JOIN farmerTBL f ON f.farmerID = r.farmerID
JOIN recivedAccTBL ra ON ra.recivedID = r.recivedID
JOIN orderDetailsTBL od ON od.recivedID = r.recivedID
WHERE (r.paymentDate BETWEEN @D1 AND @D2) AND r.status = @STATUS
```

this query does not return value if the any subquery condition equal to false
for exampel :

```
(SELECT SUM(od.quant * od.price) FROM orderDetailsTBL od WHERE od.recivedID = r. recivedID AND r.status = @STATUS AND od.calcType = 'n')  ) * ra.tips) / 100
```

if this subquery equal to false the returned value will be null

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT r.paymentDate as "Payment Date", r.recivedID as "Recived ID",
       f.farmerName as "Farmer Name", ra.tips as "percentage",     
       SUM((CASE WHEN od.calcType = 'k' THEN od.price * od.kilo
                 WHEN od.calcType = 'n' THEN od.quant * od.price
            END) * ra.tips) / 100 as [amount]
FROM recivedTBL r JOIN
     farmerTBL f
     ON f.farmerID = r.farmerID JOIN
     recivedAccTBL ra
     ON ra.recivedID = r.recivedID JOIN
     orderDetailsTBL od
     ON od.recivedID = r.recivedID
WHERE r.paymentDate BETWEEN @D1 AND @D2 AND r.status = @STATUS
GROUP BY r.paymentDate, r.recivedID, f.farmerName, ra.tips;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your entire calculation for "amount" in:

```
COALESCE(<your-calc>, 0) as [amount]
```

That will return a zero if your calculation returns NULL